# Angularjs: loop $http.post

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

**script.js**

```
for(var i = 0;i<$scope.data_acc_lv.length;i++)
        {
            var input3 = {
                "_id": $scope.accLvID + i,
                "acc_id":$scope.accLvID,
                "name": $scope.data_acc_lv[i].names,
                "read": $scope.data_acc_lv[i].read,
                "execute": $scope.data_acc_lv[i].execute,
            }
            $http.post("http://localhost:1234/access_menu",input3)
            .success(function(res){
                if(res.error == 0)
                {

                }

            });
        }
```

**script.js**

```
app.post('/access_menu',function(req,res){
    var IDMenu = req.body._id;
    var Forein = req.body.acc_id;
    var Name = req.body.name;
    var Read = req.body.read;
    var Execute = req.body.execute;

    var data = {"error":1,"Access_menu":""};
    if(!!Name && !!Read && !!Execute)
    {
        db.collection("access_menu").insert({_id:IDMenu,acc_id:Forein,name:Name,read:Read,execute:Execute},function(err,req){
            if(!!err)
            {
                data['Acess_menu'] = "input error";
            }
            else
            {
                data['error'] = 0;
                data['Access_menu'] = "input berhasil"
            }
            res.json(data);
        });
        data = {"error":1,"Access_menu":""};
    }
});
```

so I trying to input data from table to database but I always got the value from the last index (all previous value replace by the last index value), so what the cause the problem. Thank you

Comment: Your example is unclear, can you provide a plunker pls? Or your Angular data bound code and html. `.success` is deprecated `$http` method.

Comment: like @Kindzoku said you should use `.then().catch()`. What is in `$scope.accLvID` ?

Comment: Btw, does `$scope.data_acc_lv` contains array you require?

Comment: Do you have control over the Rest API? If so, this should be refactored to make a single request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the code inside the for loop in an immediately invoked function

```
     (function( i ) {
        var input3 = {
            "_id": $scope.accLvID + i,
            "acc_id":$scope.accLvID,
            "name": $scope.data_acc_lv[i].names,
            "read": $scope.data_acc_lv[i].read,
            "execute": $scope.data_acc_lv[i].execute,
        }
        $http.post("http://localhost:1234/access_menu",input3)
        .success(function(res){
            if(res.error == 0)
            {

            }

        });

      })(i);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: He can do a lot of thing, but what for? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = [];
for(var i = 0;i<$scope.data_acc_lv.length;i++){
       var input3 = {
          "_id": $scope.accLvID + i,
          "acc_id":$scope.accLvID,
          "name": $scope.data_acc_lv[i].names,
          "read": $scope.data_acc_lv[i].read,
          "execute": $scope.data_acc_lv[i].execute,
          }
         temp.push(input3)
} 
$http.post("http://localhost:1234/access_menu",temp )
        .success(function(res){
            if(res.error == 0)
            {

            }

        });
```

why not just format your array then send the whole array in on the post
then loop in your script.js?

Comment: Well, why not to use Array.map() than? `$scope.data_acc_lv.map(function(item, index){ return { '_id: item.'... }; });`